# disable links from shared view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC project that is using shared layout to render menus at the top and left of all the pages. I have a page that shows a message for inactive users. I would like to show this message in exact same layout with all the menus but the menus should be disables and user can't click on them. What can I use? Is there any thing like TagHelper I can use here?

That is the code in layout that shows the menus with linkes:

```
  !-- TOP NAVIGATION -->
 <div id="top-nav" class="span_12 section">
 <div class="span_10 content group">
    <a href="loginView.html" class="span_4 col cf-logo"><img src="~/content/images/logo.png"></a>
    <ul class="right">
        <li class="colWrap">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Dashboard","Home")" class="dashboard-view"><span class="icon-dash"></span>dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li class="colWrap">
            <!-- if there are document alerts -->
            <span class="icon-alert-13"></span>
            <!-- end if -->
            <a href="@Url.Action("Document","Document")" class="documents-view"><span class="icon-docs"></span>documents</a>
        </li>
        <li class="colWrap">
            <a href="@Url.Action("HelpCenterIndex","HelpCenter")" class="helpcenter-view"><span class="icon-help"></span>help center</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
 </div>
 <!-- LEFT SIDE NAVIGATION -->
  <div id="left-nav" class="span_1 section">
<ul id="nav-icons" class="span_12 section">
    <li class="span_12 colWrap">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Dashboard","Home")" class="dashboard-view">
            <span class="icon-dash"></span>
            Dashboard
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span_12 colWrap">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Document","Document")" class="documents-view">
            <span class="icon-docs"></span>
            Documents
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="span_12 colWrap">
        <a href="@Url.Action("HelpCenterIndex","HelpCenter")" class="helpcenter-view">
            <span class="icon-help"></span>
            Help Center
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: a lot of ways you can do this.. partial views.. child actions.. javascript..  instead of writing if/else for each item.. `$("#nav-icons a").removeAttr("href")` for example would remove all href attributes in ul id="nav-icons

Comment: This is the exact scenario where you would use razor `@helper`-s but they decided to remove them from MVC 6 for some weird reason. You can still use them if you are in MVC 5, but since you mentioned tag helpers, I assume that's not the case.

Comment: @GwynBleidd actually I am using MVC5. Any guild on how to use @helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can always implement it yourself, can't you? It would look something like this:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = "is-disabled")]
public class DisableLinkTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("is-disabled")]
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (Disabled)
        {
            output.Attributes.RemoveAll("href");
        }
    }
}
```

Import it in the views like so:

```
@addTagHelper "*, {Name of your assembly}"
```

And use it:

```
 <a is-disabled="true" href="@Url.Action("Dashboard","Home")" class="dashboard-view">
      <span class="icon-dash"></span>dashboard
 </a>
```

You can take a glimpse at the [docs about tag helpers](http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.io/projects/mvc/en/latest/views/tag-helpers/authoring.html) it literally takes a couple of minutes to grasp...

**EDIT**

In MVC 5 you can use `@helper`-s, which basically are html returning functions. You can declare one this way:

```
@helper RenderMenuLink(string url, string cssClass, string icon, string text, bool enabled)
{
    var href = "";
    if (enabled)
    {
        href = string.Format("href=\"{0}\"", url);
    }

    <a @href class="@cssClass">
        <span class="@icon"></span> @text
    </a>
}
```

And call it like you would call a regular function:

```
@RenderMenuLink(Url.Action("Dashboard","Home"), "dashboard-view", "icon-dash", "dashboard", false)
```

Comment: that is exactly what I mean, but not sure how to use Taghelpers. I am in vs2013 and MVC5. It is not available to me.

Comment: @nik I've updated the answer and included the MVC 5 helper approach

Answer (score 0):

Why you need TagHelper? You always can check your user on View and instead of `<a>` tag with `href` put on your View just text:

```
<li class="span_12 colWrap">
    @if(Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) //or any other way how you check user is active
    {
        <a href="@Url.Action("Dashboard","Home")" class="dashboard-view">
           <span class="icon-dash"></span>
           Dashboard
        </a>
    }
    else
    {
        <a class="dashboard-view">
           <span class="icon-dash"></span>
           Dashboard
        </a>        
    }
</li>
```